# Speed up initial load time for flutter web

Tags: flutter, dart, flutter-web

Does anyone have any unique resources to share on speeding up flutter web's initial load time? I've seen deferred loading (this is cross-platform and that is web-only so not a great option) and am building in release mode (with tree shaking) and the canvaskit web-renderer. The First contentful paint time in production is around 2.07s and the Time to interactive time is 2.45s. Running locally the FCP is 1.6s and the TTI is 3.04s. I've also seen as bad as close to 3s FCP and over 5s TTI. There are a lot of custom fonts and custom SVG icons that need to be loaded prior to any network calls are even made, so that may play a part. Any resources or ideas would be greatly appreciated! Building locally with `flutter build web --release --web-renderer canvaskit` results in a 4.8 MB `main.dart.js` file, which seems pretty large.

Using flutter version `3.3.8` (latest stable). Also, I plan to add a initial progress indicator (https://docs.flutter.dev/development/platform-integration/web/initialization#example-display-a-progress-indicator), but would like to boost tings in addition.